# Strong operator limit of a sequence of compact linear operators is not compact

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

**The statement of theorem:**

Let (Tₙ) be a sequence of compact linear operators from a normed space X into a Banach space Y. If (Tₙ) is uniformly operator converge say ∥Tₙ-T∥→0 then the limit operator T is compact.

**if we replace uniform operator convergengence by strong opertor convergence   ∥Tₙx-Tx∥→0 then the above theorem becomes false**

indeed i need a counter example to prove that strong limit opertor is not compact .

For this I take following counter example:
Tₙ: l²→l² defined by
Tₙx=(ξ₁,...,ξₙ,0,0,....) where x=(ξᵢ)∈ l² .
since Tₙ is linear and bounded, also dim(Tₙx)<∞ so Tₙ is compact.

but now i am stuck to prove that limit is not compact.
I also know that the identity operator is not compact since diml²=∞ but don't know how to use it
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

Linear and bounded operators need not be compact. The identity operator is a counter-example. Your $T_n$'s are compact because they have finite dimensional range.

$\|T_nx-x\|\to 0$ for every $x \in \ell^{2}$ so the limit in strong operator topology is the identity operator which is not compact.

[$\|T_nx-x\|^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |x_k|^{2}$ where $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$. Since $\sum |x_k|^{2} <\infty$ it follows  that $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |x_k|^{2} \to 0$].

Comment: Can you please explain it a little more that how we can have  ∥Tₙx-x∥→0  for every x∈l²

Comment: use the fact that $$x=\sum_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$$ and that $$T_nx=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$$

Comment: @JustDroppedIn That's a good hint, which becomes a bit more general (as you certainly are aware of). To the OP: in a (non-separable) Hilbert space $H$, you can simply fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_s: s \in S\}$. Given a finite subset $F \subseteq S$, let $p_F$ be the orthonormal projection onto the span of $\{e_s: s \in F\}$. Then the net $\{p_F\}_F$ where $F$ ranges over all finite-subsets of $S$ converges strongly to the identity on $H$.

Comment: @AyeshaAfZal I have added some details.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy thank you so much,now I completely understand